# Is It Possible To Combine These Two Queries

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need the results of Query 2 input in the slot where `[Data From Query 2 Should Go Here]` is displayed in Query 1.  I have currently just been running both queries individually and manually inputting the #'s but is it possible to run all of this as one query?

```
--Query 1
Select
case 
  when employee Like 'Ricardo%' Then '38526'
  when employee Like 'James%' Then '44187'
  else employee
end As [Employee],
COUNT(CASE WHEN d.shipped_status IN ('Hold', 'Waiting Approval') THEN d.ID else null end) As [Processing],
Count(CASE WHEN d.shipped_status = 'Shipped' THEN d.ID ELSE NULL END) As [Shipped],
Count(CASE WHEN d.shipped_status = 'Pending' THEN d.ID ELSE NULL END) As [Pending],
--This is where the Secondary Query Should Go
'' As [Data From Query 2 Should Go Here]
FROM employeeSales
WHERE d.employee IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
case 
  when employee Like 'Ricardo%' Then '38526'
  when employee Like 'James%' Then '44187'
  else employee
end


--Query 2
SELECT
case 
  when employee Like 'Ricardo%' Then '38526'
  when employee Like 'James%' Then '44187'
  else employee
end As [Employee],
COUNT(CASE WHEN b.ItemCode = '1400' THEN D.ID ELSE NULL END)
+
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.shipped_status = 'Out Of Stock' THEN a.ID ELSE NULL END)
FROM
inventory a
INNER JOIN itemsordered b
ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY 
case 
  when employee Like 'Ricardo%' Then '38526'
  when employee Like 'James%' Then '44187'
  else employee
end As [Employee]
```

Comment: Inner join? select a.*, b.* from dbo.tbla a inner join (select * dbo.tblb) b on a.id = b.id. In fact, since the two queries have the same group by, there's no reason why you cannot merge the two queries into a single one.

Comment: But their are 3 tables involved?

Comment: inner joins are not between tables. They are between data sets. Both a select statement and a table scan are data sets. You can have any number of join in a single select statement.